# Dynamic title in Wordpress homepage

Tags: customization

My homepage setting is "Display the latest post's" and I have the number set to 1. So my homepage show's my latest post.

I have YOAST plugin setting the title in homepage for now. I would like to customize the home page's title as below...

- If yoast is setting the title as "Today's breaking
  news", and if my latest post has title "Earthquake in LA"...
- I want the homepage's title tag  to have text as "Today's
  breaking news - Earthquake in LA".
- This means, the title will be dynamic and change with each new post.

I would prefer to edit code and achieve this instead of a plugin. I did a bit of searching and I did not get much help. Here is what I have now... I tried putting this into the child theme's functions.php and it did not change anything...

```
add_filter('wpseo_title', 'filter_keral_wpseo_title');
function filter_keral_wpseo_title($title) {
    if(  is_front_page() ) {
        $recent = get_posts(array(
        'author'=>1,
        'orderby'=>'date',
        'order'=>'desc',
        'numberposts'=>1
        ));
        if( $recent ){
        $title = get_the_title($recent[0]->ID);
        }
    }
    return $title;
}
```

Thanks for your time!

Comment: Welcome to [wordpress.se]. I hope you find the answer(s) you are looking for. Our site is different from most - if you have not done so yet, consider checking out the [tour](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/tour) and [help center](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/help) to find out how things work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually the above code (reposted below) worked perfectly. Guess it was a cache issue that it did not get reflected. Thanks for your time!

```
add_filter('wpseo_title', 'filter_keral_wpseo_title');
function filter_keral_wpseo_title($title) {
    if(  is_front_page() ) {
        $recent = get_posts(array(
        'author'=>1,
        'orderby'=>'date',
        'order'=>'desc',
        'numberposts'=>1
        ));
        if( $recent ){
        $title = get_the_title($recent[0]->ID);
        }
    }
    return $title;
}
```

Comment: It looks like you have self answered. Good going. Leave some time to see if anyone else has anything to contribute and then accept an answer (yours is a valid choice) so people know that there is an acceptable answer.